# Validation of multiple email list

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

am working on a validation of email list separated by semi colon, it is working fine and there is no problem 
Am uising folowing expresion `(;?\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)+`

now i want to extend this so that it can accept 
  Ending semicolon should be acceptable.
  Email address list parsing should be smarter here to filter any spaces, extra semi colons
  etc. 
  It should also accept email address separated by colons.

any help will end in thanks as am not that genius in regular expression

am doing this asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([;: ]+)?)+
```

Comment: It is working but i dont want email separated with space as Valid Emails. only colon and semi colon

Comment: The `([;: ]+)?` bit on the end says which characters you'll accept as valid between emails - if you'd like to exclude spaces (not sure why you would?) you can change it to `([;:]+)`. If my answer has helped you, please upvote and accept it :)